# Is MSDN copying Stack Exchange's profile idea to its forums?

Tags: discussion

Recently I have been seeing changes to [MSDN's Social Q&A site](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/categories) - like the introduction of badges and medals - which make it look similar to Stack Overflow.

Are they using Stack Overflow's APIs or just copying the features?

Comment: I'll go out on a limb and say they are not using SO's API's.  Copying successful features from other products?  Yeah, that's their ammo.

Comment: @LarsTech [pedant] That's their M.O. == Modus Operandi. [/pedant]

Comment: @JacobG Perhaps LarsTech really meant "that's their ammunition" (ammo is short for ammunition).  Made sense to me =)

Comment: FWIW I think it looks like crap.

Comment: @JacobG Yes, their M.O.  Too late to edit, though.

Comment: Gamification through medals and badges are hardly unique to SO...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Are they using SO's APIs or just copying the features?

They are not using our API for any of this stuff.

> Is msdn copying stack exchange's profile idea to it's forums?

I would not call it a copy, they ported a few ideas (imho very poorly) to the forum.